# Unify 2 random variables in a clause

Tags: prolog

I need to implement this functionality.

```
unify2(func1(X,Y,Z), R) => R = func1(X,X,Z)
                           R = func1(X,Y,X)
                           R = func1(X,Y,Y)
```

It's not necessary for the func1 to have 3 arguments, the number can be arbitrary. You can see that in the result there is always a couple of variables unified, the rest of the term is the same.

I would be grateful for some idea, I've been looking into copy_term but wasn't able to crack the nut yet.

Answer (score 1):

(=..)/2 (spelled [univ](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=%28=..%29/2)) it's used to decompose/assemble structures: try

```
unify2(T, R) :-
  T =.. [F,X,Y,Z],
  ( R =.. [F,X,X,Z] ; R =.. [F,X,Y,Z] ; R =.. [F,X,Y,Y] ).
```

this works for arbitrary structures with 3 arguments.

Comment: I guess it will take a while until I implement it (and accept), but I find this answer helpful. Thanks